# Simple complex modulus equality proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Kia ora,

I'm working through Quantum Computing for Computer Scientists, but am stuck on the answer for Exercise 1.2.5:

Prove that $|c_1||c_2| = |c_1c_2|$

I understand the following:

$|c_1||c_2| = √(a_1^2 + b_1^2)√(a_2^2 + b_2^2) = √((a_1^2 + b_1^2)(a_2^2 + b_2^2)) = √(a_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2)$

However, I do not understand how to make the following step:

$√(a_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2) = √((a_1b_1 - a_2b_2)^2 + (a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2)$

Expanding the suggested quadratic, Mathematica and I end up with:

$√((a_1b_1 - a_2b_2)^2 + (a_1b_2 - a_2b_1)^2) = √(a_1^2b_1^2 + a_2^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2 + a_2^2b_1^2)$

i.e. I cannot make the following translation:

$√(a_1^2b_1^2 + a_2^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2 + a_2^2b_1^2) \rightarrow √(a_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2)$

A walkthrough greatly appreciated. The provided answer (replicated above) is available at the bottom of the first page, here: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/quantum-computing-for-computer-scientists/answers-to-selected-exercises/BEE45F8C0174B4CE8EF7046291AE94F8

Ngā mihi,
Jordan

Comment: Please format math using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) rather than special characters. The answer key is just wrong. What if you next try working from the other end? $|c_1 c_2| = \ldots$

Comment: Two thanks: for 1) better latex formatting than Google suggested, and 2) confirming the text is incorrect. Answer incoming. Cheers.

Comment: I don't really have anything to add (yet) but it's cool to see another explicitly NZ user here. Kia ora bro :D

Comment: Hah - kia ora! <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @aschepler, the text answer is simply incorrect.

Working backwards:

$|c_1c_2| = |a_1a_2-b_1b_2, a_1b_2+a_2b_1| = √((a_1a_2-b_1b_2)^2 + (a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2)$

Thus we can expand both sides:

$(a_1a_2-b_1b_2)^2 = a_1^2a_2^2 - 2a_1a_2b_1b_2 + b_1^2b_2^2$

$(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2 = a_1^2b_2^2 + 2a_1a_2b_1b_2 + a_2^2b_1^2$

Therefore:

$√((a_1a_2-b_1b_2)^2 + (a_1b_2+a_2b_1)^2) = √(a_1^2a_2^2 + b_1^2b_2^2 + a_1^2b_2^2 + a_2^2b_1^2)$

Which equals the point I got to from $|c_1||c_2|$ in the OP.

Thanks @aschepler.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here is an alternate way of proceeding which may be helpful:

$
|c_1c_2|^2
=(c_1c_2)(c_1c_2)^*
=c_1c_2c_1^*c_2^*
=(c_1c_1^*)(c_2c_2^*)
=|c_1|^2|c_2|^2
$

where the second equality follows from the distributivity of the complex conjugate. Taking the square root of both sides results in

$
|c_1c_2|=|c_1||c_2|
$

Comment: This is extraordinarily elegant. I'm hoping I'll understand it in full when I get a few more chapters in :)